# How to properly use html5 input file capture attribute to take selfie photos?

Tags: javascript, html

I use that

```
<input type="file" name="avatarUpload" id="avatarUpload" capture="user" accept="image/*">
```

And I am facing 2 problems on android Chrome (pixel6)

1. it always chooses the rear camera (and not the front/selfie one)
2. the picture is 90° rotated (after I switched to the front/selfie camera)

Any idea how to fix these 2 issues ?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture) `user` should use the front camera while `environment` should use the rear camera. Maybe you need to update Chrome?

Comment: I use the latest chrome

Comment: The standard is pretty clear about `user` and `environment` values.

Comment: yes it is clear. But this just does not work. I tried both

Comment: Maybe the browser is not (yet) implemented the standard. Or it could be a bug in the browser.